# Panasonic Toughbook 55 (FZ-55) No speaker sound on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10

Long story short: Sound output via speakers doesn't work on my Panasonic Toughbook 55 only on Ubuntu. It works on Windows 10 though.

I ran `alsa-info.sh` from http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh and the result is here:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=6f367c5eb97ddd024587420e02d6f2fa21e10a08

I have also used `hw-probe`:

https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=e5c25a6e55

I've tried changing output devices, fiddling with `alsamixer`, but I wasn't able to hear anything.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base` and also purged their configs as well.

The volume display does bob up and down when playing on speakers.

The headphone jack does work, as well as the microphones and cameras.

Anybody use Toughbooks and have this problem before?

Comment: Try disabling "Auto-Mute Mode".

Comment: Thanks @CL., tried `amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled`, and it reports that it is indeed disabled, but no sound still.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed something similar on a semi-rugged Panasonic CF-SX2 by using `hdajackretask`.

I think your options are:

- Wait until fixes arrive by updates.
- Wait until someone posts a tested solution somewhere on the internet for your model.
- Meddle around with `hdajackretask` and hope for the best.

***When trying out random changes it is very important to write down the initial state of settings for yourself so you can avoid breaking everything further. Still there are probably risks of permanently damaging your hardware.***

You have to experiment for yourself what you need overridden for your model. I don't remember the details, but I think you at least need to restart the music app to test changes. Hopefully restarting the whole pc was not required. After finding a change that makes speakers work, I recommend also testing the built-in microphone, sound-out port (headphones) and sound-in port (external microphone) since your changes might have broken those. One way to test microphone for me was using the barely visible audiometer on user portrait at this [open-source browser based conference call solution](https://meet.jit.si).

#### CF-SX2 initial state

Without "Show unconnected pins" (without override ticked):

- Internal Mic, Pin ID: 0x12; Internal mic
- Internal Speaker; Pin ID: 0x14; Internal Speaker
- Black Headphone, Front side; Pin ID 0x15; Headphone
- Black Mic, Front Side; Pin ID 0x18; Microphone

With "Show unconnected pins" (the ones with override are):

- nothing

#### CF-SX2 solution

Needed to override the following pins in the following ways:

- 0x17=internal speaker
- 0x1a=internal speaker
- 0x1b=internal speaker

---

[Here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1553947&sid=fd6cab54ec3e3477e636773b6cc95f14#p1553947) someone fixed their Panasonic CF-52 Toughbook speaker on Linux Mint by overriding a pin with `hdajackretask` (0x13=internal speaker).

If you comment your working pin (and maybe initial state as well) then I can alter this answer to be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

My answer comes from here.This is for the CF-31, but I suspect it's a similar problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjmHVgCSpQQ

Basically you need to edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf, and add the lines described in the video. If this helps let me know and I will properly transcribe the full steps. Should be a quick fix if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Mint 20 on a Toughbook FZ-55 and everything worked straight out of the box. No problems with the audio, wifi, or bluetooth.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu site. Suggesting a different flavour of Linux doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with the CF-series and Ubuntu. `hdajackretask` is how i fixed. for some reason overriding the pins makes it work. it took me a few attempts before the sound worked.

if anyone else comes across this issue, the Toughbooks make great linux laptops. i cannot recommend a more reliable laptop.